# My android app does not respond to ir remote ok button

Tags: android

Please forgive me if I have not made this post clear enough.

I have GridView with ImageView and TextView that are being filled by a custom adapter.

When I highlight an item in the GridView and press the IR Remote (OK) button it only returns with stat pressed animation.

Now I have tried a KeyCode listener that returns the keycode numbers and I found out all the KeyCodes except for the OK button did not return anything.

Now I have also tried all KeyCode Event such as ENTER, DPAD_CENTER, ACTION_DOWN and OnTouchListeners nothing worked.

I have also added the tag stat pressed in the gridview xml to false.

There is no way to debug this app in debugger because it is a Smart TV

**ChannelListAdapter.java**

```
package com.showhd.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.showhd.R;
import com.showhd.common.Shared;
import com.showhd.data.TVChannel;
import com.showhd.stb.STBTV;
import com.showhd.stb.VStreaming;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public class ChannelListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TVChannel> 
 {

    private Context context;

    private int layoutId;
    private List<TVChannel> data = null;

    public ChannelListAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<TVChannel> data) {
        super(context, layoutId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
        this.data = data;

        Shared.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(context));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageviewIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_channel_icon);

            holder.textviewChannelCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_channel_caption);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ImageView imageView = holder.imageviewIcon;
        Shared.imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).getIconUrl(), holder.imageviewIcon, Shared.options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

            public void onLoadingStarted() {

            }

            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {

            }

            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                int realWidth = loadedImage.getWidth();
                int realHeight = loadedImage.getHeight();

                // Resize image
                Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
                int imageWidth = screenWidth / 10;
                imageView.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
                imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(((float)imageWidth / (float)realWidth) * realHeight);
            }

            public void onLoadingCancelled() {

            }
        });
        holder.textviewChannelCaption.setText(data.get(position).getCaption());



        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


            STBTV.channelId = data.get(position).getId();
          //  VStreaming.streamVideo1(data.get(position).getStreamingUrl());
            String g = data.get(position).getStreamingUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,VStreaming.class);
            intent.putExtra("Vpath", g);
            context.startActivity(intent);



            }
        });



    return convertView;

    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textviewChannelCaption;
        ImageView imageviewIcon;
    }


}
```

**stb_channel_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_channel_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

         android:state_pressed="false"
       android:focusable="false"       
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_channel_caption"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**stb_tv.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_packages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bg_title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/packages"
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_packages"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_categories"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/lawn_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:alpha=".80"
                android:text="@string/categories"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_categories"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" >

            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_epgs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >

            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="25dp" >
            </GridView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you press OK button one more time?

Comment: Nothing if it did something i would of wrote about it.